# Why is the @RequestBody not parsing my json request properly

Tags: json, angular, rest

I have an @RestController with the following method that is not parsing the json request properly:

```
@Transactional
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = { "/correctiveaction" }, method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public ResponseEntity<CorrectiveActionView> createCorrectiveAction(@RequestBody CorrectiveAction object) {

    log.info("createCorrectiveAction(): called...");
```

The Corrective Action does not contain all my data from my JSON request from angular2.  I will paste the JSON at the end.  For some reason, only one objects for the "comments" appears in the CorrectiveAction object when it hits the controller.  There should be two.

I notice in the comments objects, there is an extra field that seems to be getting generated by JSON.stringify() call on the front end.  The field is "_$visited": true.  The two attachment objects do not have this field and they are both new objects like the comments objects.  This puzzles me.

So I guess I have two questions: 1.  Why is the JSON.stringify() call placing those fields in the JSON request comments and not the attachments, and 2. Is that what is causing the problem, or is it something else?

Please let me know if you need more details.

Here is the angular2 jason request code:

```
  createCorrectiveAction(correctiveAction: CorrectiveAction) {
const myjson = JSON.stringify(correctiveAction);
console.log('myjson=' + myjson);
this.http.post(`${CREATE_URL}`, JSON.stringify(correctiveAction), httpOptions)
  .pipe(map(payload => ({ type: 'CREATE_HOME_CORRECTIVE_ACTION', payload })))
  .subscribe(action => {
    this.store.dispatch(action);
    this.store.dispatch({ type: 'SELECT_ADD_CORRECTIVE_ACTION', payload: action.payload });
  });
```

}

Here is the json data for the request:

```
    {
  "id": null,
  "externalId": "",
  "actionCode": 2,
  "shortDescription": "s15",
  "descriptionOfFirmCorrections": "d15",
  "creatdBy": "",
  "creatdDt": null,
  "mdfydBy": "",
  "mdfydDt": null,
  "attachments": [
    {
      "atchmntId": null,
      "externalId": "",
      "docUpldRqrd": "",
      "filName": "f16",
      "filPath": "",
      "filSize": null,
      "filType": "",
      "fileguid": "",
      "requestObjectId": "",
      "userId": "PCOCAR",
      "virusAfctd": "",
      "virusNtfctnRqrd": "",
      "virusScanDttm": null,
      "virusScanRqrd": "",
      "virusScanRslt": "",
      "comments": "f16",
      "numOfPages": null,
      "refCd": null,
      "creatdBy": "",
      "creatdDt": null,
      "mdfydBy": "",
      "mdfydDt": null,
      "correctiveAction": null
    },
    {
      "atchmntId": null,
      "externalId": "",
      "docUpldRqrd": "",
      "filName": "f17",
      "filPath": "",
      "filSize": null,
      "filType": "",
      "fileguid": "",
      "requestObjectId": "",
      "userId": "PCOCAR",
      "virusAfctd": "",
      "virusNtfctnRqrd": "",
      "virusScanDttm": null,
      "virusScanRqrd": "",
      "virusScanRslt": "",
      "comments": "f17",
      "numOfPages": null,
      "refCd": null,
      "creatdBy": "",
      "creatdDt": null,
      "mdfydBy": "",
      "mdfydDt": null,
      "correctiveAction": null
    }
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": null,
      "externalId": "",
      "creatdBy": "",
      "creatdDt": null,
      "mdfydBy": "",
      "mdfydDt": null,
      "comment": "c16",
      "correctiveAction": null,
      "_$visited": true
    },
    {
      "id": null,
      "externalId": "",
      "creatdBy": "",
      "creatdDt": null,
      "mdfydBy": "",
      "mdfydDt": null,
      "comment": "c17",
      "correctiveAction": null,
      "_$visited": true
    }
  ],
  "observations": [
    {
    ...
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after consulting one of my colleagues, the problem was on the java side.  I didn't realize that I had the hashCode() and equals() methods in the Comment.java entity.  The equals() method was using the 'id' as the comparison which, in both of the comments objects, were equal to null.  I believe that this caused the @RequestBody to consider the two comments as a duplicate, so it dropped one of them.

```
    /* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Comment)) {
        return false;
    }
    Comment other = (Comment) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```